# UITextField Cursor is showing so small on begin editing iPhone 6

Tags: uitextfield, uitextview

UITextField Cursor is showing so small[image] on begin editing iPhone 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to invalid font applied on textfield, may be it will help someone else.